# Power BI Service Full Screen mode not responding

Tags: browser, powerbi, microsoft-edge, fullscreen

We have published Power BI reports to Power BI Service. There if we try to enter the full screen mode, suddenly all the visuals stop responding. Ex. Slicers, tooltips everything stops responding
As soon as we hit Esc key or exit Full screen mode, everything works. Has anyone come across this problem?

Note: We have tried in Edge browser. Same thing is working in Google Chrome browser but not in Firefox. Tried clearing cache in the browser but same problem is coming in Edge and Firefox

Thanks and Regards,
Sridatta

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in Edge. It works well in full screen mode. Which version of Edge are you using? I suggest that you install the latest version of Edge, disable all the extensions in Edge, clear all the data in Edge and test again. Besides, I suggest that you ask questions in [Power BI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/) so that you can get better help.

Comment: Thank you very much @YuZhou Edge version is 98.0.1108.50. Will check out in Power BI Community also.

Comment: Is there any error in console opening F12 dev tools when you're in Edge full screen mode? It's strange that it doesn't work in Edge. If disabling extensions and clearing browser data still doesn't work, you can try to run the page in Edge InPrivate windows to see if it works.